# GRUB2: Add second set of flags as option for every kernel

Tags: fedora, grub2

I am using Fedora, and GRUB2 is my bootloader. I know how to change the flags in `/etc/default/grub` just fine, and when I remake my configuration, this is reflected in my boot menu, and updates automagically whenever I update my kernel (as I do regularly).

I want to have a second GRUB option like this, but with an alternate set of flags. So, when I power on and arrive at GRUB, I want to be presented with either of these two options. I understand how to add a custom line to the 40_custom file and add a new menu item, but this seems to me to be attached to the particular kernel version I would put in that item. How can I add a sort of alternate flags option which updates à la the usual one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any other file (like 39_custom) for example. Basically it is a shell script that can output the configuration in similiar format You write it plain to 40_custom (and possibly some comments). So You are free to detected the most recent available kernel in that script and build Your custom line using that information.
Just take care to not output any garbage from that script to STDOUT besides the valid menuentry-stuff (and possible commented lines) that You otherwise hardcode in 40_custom.

You can also take a look in the default config file (10_linux or such) how the current kernel is searched for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my solution: Fedora 30 stores menu entries in `/boot/loader/entries/` (the format is simple and obvious). I set up a script in `/etc/kernel.postinst.d/` to copy the newly-installed kernel to `/boot/vmlinuz` and the intramfs similarly to a generic name, then set a new `/boot/loader/entries/` file with reference to these files (I tried symlinks as well but this didn't work for some reason: GRUB reported that the files were not found).